# C String Literals and Pointers Assignment

Tags: c

I was looking at tutorials for C and pointers on the internet and found a debugging example and am wondering how to fix this block of code? I have been looking for a while and can't find out how to make it work. I want to replace the `'i'` in `"Harris"` with an `"a"`.

```
char * ptr = (char *) "Harris";

ptr[4]="a";
```

Comment: String Literals CANNOT be modified (except on ancient hardware not relevant here) You can use a *compound literal* `char *ptr = (char[]){ "Harris" };` (C99+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can assign a constant to a char pointer, you can't normally write to it. Fix your code:

```
char ptr []= "Harris";
```

For not-your-legacy code use -fwritable-strings.

Comment: So I broke my own rule about answer and close because on reload after answer someone found a dupe target.

Comment: There are only about 100 on the topic `:)`

Answer (score 2):

ptr[4]='a';

Single quotes for character constants.

Comment: Which will buy a SegFault in this case. (but your note on quotes is correct).

Comment: So, a strdup then.  Hard to answer these on a phone waiting for Chinese takeout.